# Helios (html5up) and flexslider2 (woothemes)

Tags: jquery, html, css, templates, flexslider

So I have hacked the Helios theme from [html5up](http://html5up.net/helios) all to pieces, and I'm sure I've broken all of the golden html5/css3 rules.

The main issue I'm having can be viewed here: [redlighttuesday.com/photos.php](http://www.redlighttuesday.com/photos.php)
I'd like to remove all of the index numbers from the above and have the navigation arrows display on hover as can be seen in the woo themes flexslider demo.

It's probably something silly like where I'm placing the files (I've tried to maintain the Helios directory structure), or how i'm linking style sheets (helios uses an init.js and then  the css files, i think this might be part of the issue as well).  Any help/direction is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Also, I've used a simple php script to populate the pictures.       <?php
$dir = 'pic';
$photos = array_diff(scandir($dir),array('..', '.'));
shuffle($photos);
foreach ($photos as $photo) {
echo '<li><img src="'.$dir.'/'.$photo.'" /></li>';
}
?>